# Array type in table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have data with a single column of and array of IDs that are **not** in JSON format.

```
"100,101,102"
```

I would like to be able to query rows with something like

```
WHERE "101" IN idarray
```

but it appears that the [ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/arrays) type is not supported as a column type.

Is there an approach in BigQuery where an array or delimited string can be queried for containing an element?

For example in PostgreSQL I can use the array [contains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) element syntax **@>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT idarray FROM
  (SELECT "100,101,102" AS idarray),
  (SELECT "200,201,202,1010" AS idarray),
) as YourTable
WHERE "," + idarray + "," CONTAINS "," + "101" + ","
```

Same as above but "adopted" for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT "100,101,102" AS idarray UNION ALL
  SELECT "200,201,202,1010" AS idarray
)
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONCAT(",", idarray, ",") LIKE CONCAT("%,", "101", ",%")
```

or

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT "100,101,102" AS idarray UNION ALL
  SELECT "200,201,202,1010" AS idarray
)
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(idarray, r"\b101\b")
```

or  ("pure" Standard SQL style)

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT "100,101,102" AS idarray UNION ALL
  SELECT "200,201,202,1010" AS idarray
)
SELECT idarray
FROM YourTable, UNNEST(SPLIT(idarray)) AS id1
WHERE id1 = "101"
```

Comment: Interestingly, I need to use Legacy SQL on this approach. Probably not a problem, but any ideas why this won't work with standard SQL?

Comment: Any data on the performance implications of the REGEXP_CONTAINS approach? The SQL itself is "cleaner".

Comment: usually regexp functions are expensive - but really depends on actual data & volume  - you should experiment with diff approaches to pick best for you. I added one more btw